# auto-ajustar posición de elementos al maximizar un widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qt-designer

Quisiera saber como puedo cambiar la posisión de los elementos de un MainWindow en pyqt, es decir, que cuando la ventana se maximize los elementos conserven su ubicacion respectiva.

espero puedan ayudar

EJEMPLO:

quiero que el pushbutton que agrego a la mainwindow, al momento de maximizarse tenga la misma posicion que cuando se maximiza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la imagen tengo el boton pegado al costado de la ventana, pero al maximizarse no se pone en esa pocisión.

Al momento de maximizar el boton cambia la posision:

Ahora ya no esta pegado al contorno de la ventana

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese es muy general, ¿estas usando layouts?, podrias proveer un [mcve]

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con posición?, ¿posicion relativa o absoluta?

Comment: @eyllanesc. Absoluta es decir que si un boton esta a 30px del marco derecho por ejemplo.. cuando se máximize la ventana debe de estar a 30px del marco igual

Comment: Segun veo en el arbol de propiedades no usas layouts por lo que la posicion no deberia cambiar, asi que no esperaria ese problema, podrias compartir el archivo .ui

Comment: Tu no quieres que se mantenga la posicion absoluta, tu quieres que se mantenga en posicion relativa al borde de la ventana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segun veo tu deseas que la posicion relativa del boton respecto a la ventana se mantenga constante, por lo que la posicion absoluta del boton respecto a la ventana debe modificarse. Un QWidget tiene una posicion relativa al topLeft(esquina izquierda superior), por lo que en tu caso debemos usar algun evento que indique la ventana principal ha cambiado de posicion, y ese evento es el `resizeEvent()`.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(640, 480)
        widget = QWidget()

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.position_x_rel = 30 
        self.button = QPushButton(widget)
        self.button.move(0, 240)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        geo = self.button.geometry()
        geo.moveRight(self.width() - self.position_x_rel)
        self.button.setGeometry(geo)
        super(MainWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```